# Would 2 consecutive .load calls in jquery execute async?

Tags: javascript, jquery

In a script like the following, would the `load` functions be called in asynchronously or one after another?

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {

          $("#TheLink").click(){        
                $("#PlaceToUpdate1").load("/Controller/Method/View1");
                $("#PlaceToUpdat2").load("/Controller/Method/View2");

          }

        });
    }); 
</script>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Asynchronously, by default. If you need them to be one-after-the-other, you can do a few things:

1. Place the second in the callback of the first.
2. Set `$.ajax({async:false})`
3. You could possibly even set these up in a queue.

The cleanest way is probably option 2.

Comment: Lol... love the three word answer. +1 :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the full call for load is:

```
load( url, [data], [callback] )
```

the third optional parameter is a callback method that will be called when the asynchronous load method completes.